# Was swastika a popular symbol among Slavs and/or Proto-Indo-Europeans?

Tags: history, religion

It seems to me that many Russian nationalists and neo-paganists currently believe that swastika was a Solar symbol or a symbol of fortune in ancient Slavic folklore.

There are multiple paintings by nationalist painters and other art that features swastika.
Examples of articles which claim that swastika was an ancient Slavic symbol:

- http://www.nasled.org/vera/Simvoly.htm
- http://s-mahat.ru/cgi-bin/index.cgi?cont=26
- http://www.dazzle.ru/spec/svastika4.shtml
- http://www.slavianin.ru/svastika/stati/svastika-drevniy-slavyanskiy-simvol.html
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MvLJdbSUVXQ
- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=HZTetihA5RI&feature=related

This film claims that swastica is "the most ancient symbol of the Slavs":

- http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=54Eq0-PWH0U&feature=related

On the other hand the advocates of these theories explain the fact that swastika is not widely represented in museums of ancient Slavic culture by the claim that it is due to a conspiracy by the Bolshevicks/Jews/ZOG to hide items with swastika from the people.

So what is the reality. Was swastika ever a Slavic symbol before WWII?

Comment: from the wikipedia page on the sqastika, we can see that it was in use throughout europe for thousands of years before WWII as to the exact use or meaning of the symbol it verried or is unknown depending on the culture, but the article shows that one of the earliest known examples is from the Ukraine at 10,000 BCE. so its been around for quite some time. its found around the world as well, in india as well as rome. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swastika

Comment: @Himarm the Ukraine claim links to a BBC article which refers to this bird figure: http://news.bbcimg.co.uk/media/images/78456000/jpg/_78456827_mezin_bird624.jpg It seems what is claimed to be "swastika" is just an ornament which resembles swastika only distantly and it is unclear whether it is a symbol of something rather than just a decoration.

Comment: that was just the earliest mentioned thing, as you see their are pictures of roman tiles with swastika's on them as well as other objects from 100s to thousands of years before  WWII that were found in Europe as well as Asia.

Comment: @Himarm OK. I am interested specifically about Slavs and Proto-Indo-Europeans. And not whether they used ornaments with swastika-like patterns, but whether it was a symbol of something.

Comment: http://sacred-texts.com/sym/mosy/mosy06.htm
this article, again a continuation from the wikepedia says, that it was infact found on slavic, and armenian(proto-indo-european) artifacts and is/was considered both a symbol of the sun as well as for eternity. the book quoted was also written in the 1800's before any nazi bias could influence writing.

Comment: @Himarm I hevent find any references to the Slavs there. Also I am more interested un modern views.

Comment: Why is the downvote?

Comment: how modern do you want, you should specify then, Fact is there are artifacts all over Europe and Asia with swastika's on them, you had modern countries using swastikas up until the point the nazi's claim it as a symbol in Europe. there are very few people who have followed pagan religions in the last 500ish years in Europe. so evidence is going to be fairly old in that department. your post is that people claim they used to be used, but that their aren't many examples in museums because of the jews, however, i have just shown you tons of artifacts from the areas in question.

Comment: i see that you already asked this 2 years ago on history, and you didn't like the answer you received. its not going to get much better then that. that wikipedia article literally has everything about swastikas pertaining to the slavic peoples.
http://history.stackexchange.com/questions/2754/was-swastika-really-a-popular-symbol-among-slavs-and-or-ancient-indo-europeans

Comment: @Himarm I am not interested in some random places in Europe and Asia. My question is concrete, it is about Slavs and Proto-Indo-Europeans. It is not about scytheans, celt, iranians, greeks or anybody else. If u have an answer, make it.

Comment: @Anixx - can you pin down the PIE more? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proto-Indo-Europeans - they are defined via a hypothetical language, and possibly lived in some huge area somewhen between 4ka and 7.5ka BC. Would swastika-finds in that huge region in that huge timeframe satisfy you, or would there need to be a post-it attached  saying 'me-likey'? Or are you more specific in terms of region and timeframe?

Comment: @bukwyrm Proto-Indo-Euopeans are generally thought existed 4000-3000 BC (this is language reconstruction horizon). Swastika was not a PIE symbol.

Comment: @Anixx that's what i was getting at - you mentioned in your comment to Himarm: "My question is concrete, it is about Slavs and Proto-Indo-Europeans" - so i was wondering